# Enabling Theme in Open edx

Tags: openedx

I have installed `Open Edx` and its working fine, but now I am trying to enable theme through Comprehensive theme option in `lms.env.json`.

As I turn `ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEME: -> true` the `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` is triggered.

Any idea what could be the missing node or problem.

Comment: What do kind installation you have? ,devstack, fullstack or native?

Answer (score 3):

For the LMS, you edit /edx/app/edxapp/lms.env.json 
to set

```
"ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING": true ,
```

For Studio, you edit /edx/app/edxapp/cms.env.json
to set

```
"ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING": true ,
```

For the E-commerce service, you edit /edx/etc/ecommerce.yml 
to set

```
ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING: true ,
```

Check documentation link :
http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/changing_appearance/theming/enable_themes.html